# Where should I put common stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My SQL Server 2008 has

1. one central database that has some global functions, e.g. mapping to specified client DB.
2. 50+ client DBs
3. Master DB.. (MS Default)
4. ASPState for session.

Now I'm trying to add this stored procedure `usp_RethrowError` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296.aspx) which is return a message from `try...catch..` of SQL to my server.

Since the stored procedure is a common sp, I want to use it in the central DB and all client DBs. Where should I put it? in the central or duplicate it in each client DB?

Is there any issue or performance drawback if the stored proc is placed in the central, caz in the client DB, I have to write something like `[central].dbo.usp_RethrowError`

What about put it in the master db?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is largely a matter of taste, and of the specific circumstances.  There are no performance implications to calling a procedure from another database.

I generally recommend against putting stored procedures in the master DB and generally reserve that for system use.

There are some cases where replicating the procedures makes sense (such as when you think there is a chance you may eventually separate those procedures into multiple servers).  I frequently put utility procedures and functions in a separate database named utility.

This makes it easier to maintain than giving each database their own copy (only one place to change code if I want to add functionality or discover a subtle bug), but it also avoids poluting the master database, and makes it easy to backup and migrate all of my utility functions when a new server is brought online.

Comment: If there are no performance implications, then the StoredProc should be added in `Master` or My `Central`. So what's your option for these two dbs. Does `Master` cause maintenance/upgrade problems?

Comment: Your central sounds like the same as my utility database, which is what I normally recommend.  As for using master, I don't like to put them there just because it seems disorganized to put any user defined object in the master DB, and the master DB is often treated differently by the DBA when it comes to making backups.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether any of your client database's will ever have to move server, without the rest of the databases.

Moving the client database to another server, which doesn't also include your `central` database will cause an error to be thrown. So in this case, I would add the stored procedure to each database.

If the databases are never going to be individually moved to another server, then I would add the stored procedure to the `master` database.

Comment: The dbs won't be moved individually to another server. So what the benefits that adding it in `Master` than `Central`.

Comment: I think the question should be the other way round? What's the purpose of creating a `Central` database?

Comment: I understand that a SP that contains common business logic should be added in `Central`, but not sure about a sys utility-like SP. I guess you probably mean never add things in `Master`, since I got a customlised `Central` DB.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other considerations, you may also want to look at using a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx).  That way you could create a centralized database for your common procedures [central], but have your code pointing to a synonym for those procs.  In the future, if you need to move to a self-contained version, move the centralized procs to your local databases, and drop the synonym.

Comment: Have read about `synonym` from MSDN, seems it is more used for user data operations (`select`). Does it suit for Utility/Common Function?

Comment: Any time you need to reference a specific object that is either remote or local to your current operation, then a synonym may be used.  It's simply a shortcut; the benefit is that if you ever need to update the location, you can drop and recreate the synonym without touching your calling code.

Comment: I see, do you use synonym for every table or StoredProc in `Central` or `Master` in your project? May be the only drawback for a synonym is that it has to be duplicated in every client DB, which increase a bit maintenance works.

Comment: Anyway it is still a good suggestion. So what's your option of `Master` or my `Central`?